# Start activity from a dialog created in a utility class - Android

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have an activity which calls a method in a utility class. This method checks if the user is eligible. If they are it returns true. If they aren't, it returns false but creates and opens an Alert dialog which explains why. In one case when the user clicks the ok button in the dialog it will start a new activity. The code for the setting of the dialog on click is below. The dialog is a custom dialog which simply extends `AlertDialog.Builder`.

```
 if(dialog.getBodyText().toString().equals(prospectError)){
            dialog.setOkClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(((Dialog)dialog).getContext(),NotEligibleActivity_.class);
                    ((Dialog)dialog).getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

When I click the ok button the dialog closes but the activity isn't started. I am passing the activity into the `checkEligiblity` method as the context. This is used when initializing the dialog.

Comment: put a log inside the `if` statement I bet it never resolves to `true`

Comment: I put a break point in the if statement and it does hit the onclick setter. Also my code is if(not eligbile){setOnClick to start new activity}else{setOnClick to close dialog}. I set the else to start the activity as well as a check but that also resulted in the activity not starting

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was a dumb mistake on my part

Answer (score 0):

You should use the activity context, not the dialog context.

```
public class Example extends Activity
{
    Example instance = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instance = this;
     ...            
    }
}
```

and use `instance` variable instead of `((Dialog)dialog).getContext()`

Comment: I've tried using the activity context. In the activity i call checkEligible(this). In the utility class I use the activity I passed in as the context to create the dialog. So they should both be equal to the same thing in the end

Comment: The two are not the same, one is type Acitvity and one is type Dialog. Another option is to use getBaseContext() instead of ((Dialog)dialog).getContext().

Comment: the dialog's context is the activity, your answer is wrong.